# What's the point of using parenthesis in regex if you're not remembering the matched part?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why would you use `\(?:\d+)alp*ha\` rather than `\\d+alp*ha\` ??

Comment: Who are you really working for?  The CIA?  The mob?  Aliens from a far-off solar system totally unlike our own?

Comment: Javascript doesn't allow you to delimit regular expressions with backslash. Did you mean slash instead?

Comment: @Mark Byers I'm often saddened by evidence that so many people in this world consider \ and / to be the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, there is no reason to add the parenthesis.  However consider the following:

```
/(?:\d+A?)*alp*ha/
```

In that example, the parenthesis define a group that can be repeated.  This would be impossible to express without parenthesis.  (Without parenthesis - `/\d+A?*alp*ha/` - is something completely different.)

Answer (score 1):

In the example, there is no point to using the non-capturing parentheses; they may be a leftover relic from a previous more complex expression.

In general, if you have a more complex expression, perhaps with alternatives or you need to qualify a string, then the non-capturing parentheses are useful.

```
(?:\d+|abc)?alp*ha
```

This requires the non-capturing parentheses.

You probably have a problem with escaped (or unescaped) backslashes in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression syntax is like algebraic syntax in that there are **operators** with **precedence**.  The parenthesis (all sorts of them) do double-duty: explicit control of operator binding *and* various sorts of grouping, stashing, and searching tweaks.